# libgit: Fastest way of fetching files in a commit

Tags: c++, git, performance, libgit2

I need to iterate over a repository's commits and fetch affected files for each commit. This is my **huge** performance bottleneck currently.

I've a C++ wrapper around the libgit functions but this snippet should be understandable enough.

```
std::vector<std::string> Commit::getAffectedFiles() const {
  git_tree* tree = nullptr;
  git_tree* tree2 = nullptr;
  int error = git_commit_tree(&tree, get());
  throw_on_error(error);

  try {
    error = git_commit_tree(&tree2, parent(0).get());
  } catch (GitException e) {
    tree2 = nullptr; // probably initial commit
  }
  git_diff* diff = nullptr;
  git_diff_tree_to_tree(&diff, getRepo(), tree2, tree, 0);  

  std::vector<std::string> ret;
  git_diff_foreach(diff,
  [](const git_diff_delta* entry, float progress, void* payload) {
    std::string str = entry->old_file.path;
    ((std::vector<std::string>*)payload)->push_back(str);
    return 0;
  }, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &ret);
  git_tree_free(tree);
  git_tree_free(tree2);
  git_diff_free(diff);
  return ret; 
}
```

I can only hope I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here.

---

For example

```
git log --stat > /dev/null
```

is way faster, and provides the same information.

---

perf reports most usage on `git__strncmp`, `git_buf_rfind_next` and `git_tree__parse` in order.

---

I know this is IO heavy, but I don't see an easy way of reducing this or running this in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

That is equivalent to what git does internally, though git itself has had more people looking at it for performance and libgit2 hasn't had nearly as much investment in that.

However, a few patches[0] recently got merged into libgit2's `master` branch which can cut up to 40% of the tree parsing time. I'd recommend to try that out and see what numbers you get (the patches should be easily backportable to earlier versions as well).

Also take into account that your version of git is most likely compiled in release mode and libgit2 by default builds in debug mode, so if you haven't activated release mode, run cmake with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`. This also speeds up these parsing operations significantly.

[0] Specifically PR [3508](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3508) and the commits [0174f2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/0174f21b0ab1abb24496939d95c0cc84187aba00) and [fc4364](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/fc4364696556678f4cac4f6cefed17b94b4ec776)

Comment: I have installed libgit2 via apt-get, so that should be release mode. However it is version 0.23.0 which might not be ideal. 
I'll try to build it myself against HEAD and see what it's going to get me. 
Thanks!